# Webform not recognizing my PDF as a PDF

Tags: pdftex, pdf

Sometimes when i try to upload my resume onto an online form the site wont accept my file saying something along the lines of:

> The file you uploaded is not a PDF file.

This has happened to me a few times now. Has this anything to do with the fact that it is a latex created file? Has anyone had this before?

Comment: A bit too vague, don't you think?

Comment: @egreg I know but that is simply all it says! And i really just wanted to know if more people had it. I tried several PDFs.

Comment: I've had PDFs rejected on the grounds that the system could not convert them to PDF. I don't know if that is related or not. PDF -> PS (with ghostscript) -> PDF seems to work. (This is silly: the result is essentially graphics and huge. But that it seemed to like :(.)